Need help in understanding the sentence: "아버지 등에 업고 놀러 왔습니다!"
I am reading a manhwa, and I came across this sentence: 아버지 등에 업고 놀러 왔습니다!
I tried to translate it myself, yet to no avail.
The context is like this:

Character A comes to her friend's house and there meets with his mother. After some talk Character A learns that her and her friend's families are business partners. She thinks that her friend's mother sees her differently because of this. Character A imagines that this sentence (↑↑↑) is how she sounds in her friend's mother's head.

After some time of search I got this translation: "I came to play, piggybacked by my dad!". I am not convinced that this is the correct translation. Could someone help me understand, what does this sentence mean?
I suppose it conveys a meaning of the girl seeming arrogant to her friend's mother? Yet how it can be translated to Enlgish?
EDIT: added screenshots for clearer context



I think something is missing here. Could you post screenshots for more context?

@user17915 Yeah, sure! Edited the original post. Sorry for not providing screenshots beforehand!

it may be 아버지(를) 등에 업고 놀러 왔습니다!(not 'piggybacked by my dad')
It may imply the influence of the father coming from a business relationship.
'A' piggybacks her father, so she has some influence now.
Because she may have influence over her father in business.
Before, friend's mother didn't know about it, so 'A' didn't have the power coming from her father.
Friend's mother is now uncomfortable because A's presence reminds friend's mother of A's father, almost as if it seems like 'A' is piggybacking her father.
But I need to read the 만화 to explain it correctly with confidence.

Thank you for explanation! I added some screenshots for more context, if it helps. Sorry for not providing them earlier!

It means she carries the influence of her father. With a smile, she implies she's either kidding or feeling 겸연쩍음.

This is the first time I've encountered this expression, so it's okay not to worry about it too much.
